# how to know my webview javascript code in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Actually, I am using **web view** in my Application, and I need to hide some content in **web view** when the page is loaded. I found the way how to do it from [HERE](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/)

But I am confused that what my **javascript** code would be that I need to write in for hiding something.

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript: your java script code");  // where is my javascript code ??
```

So "your javascript code" where can I find it. It would be great if someone could explain with an example.

I hope You got what I am looking for ?

Thanks for any help .

Comment: You need to add your .js into project Assets folder and access it

Comment: Say e.g In www.google.com page I want to hide Gmail link .. How would I do it ?

Comment: How the js will be added in my code and how would i write javascript code from that file . Actually I am new to android, so apology for any bad :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put Javascript code directly after "javascript:". For example:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Test');");
```

or

```
webview.loadUrl(
    "javascript:" + 
    "(function() {" + 
        "var e = document.getElementById('rootDiv');" + 
        "if(e) { " + 
            "e.style.display = 'none';" + 
        "}" + 
     "})()");
```

EDIT:

so to hide the link you mentioned it would be something like this:

```
(function(a) {
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        if(a[i].href == "https://plus.google.com/u/0/?tab=wX") {
            a[i].style.display = "none"; 
            break;
        }
    }
})(document.getElementsByTagName("a"))
```

Then to your webview:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:" + 
"(function(a) { " + 
    "for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) { " + 
        "if(a[i].href == 'https://plus.google.com/u/0/?tab=wX') { " + 
            "a[i].style.display = 'none'; " + 
            "break; " +
        "} " +
    "} " +
 "})(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please read my question carefully, I know I will put my code after javascript: , but my problem is I don't know where this code will come from. E.g I want to hide Gmail button from the page www.google.com .. Now what will be the code now after javascript:         ?

Comment: I do not understand your dilemma - you should just write it??? Or I misunderstood You?

Comment: I will try to explain now.

Comment: Thanks again.. Now you got me.. from where I can find my required code ? By inspecting element something like this ?

Comment: I need to see it from page source ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You should inspect the html source to find out how to grab the button's node.

Comment: its hard to find from mobile browser :( can you suggest something to getting from there ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48711/discussion-between-nadeem-gc-and-tomasz-gawel)

Comment: I successfully did this. NOw just a quick question. Can I do this at start of the loading page ? instead of onFinished loading page ? I tried it in onPageStarted funtion but it didn't worked thre .